# Why am I getting a 403 Forbidden error in Django when I do a POST request with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

In Django Console I'm getting this message in red:

```
[16/Jan/2015 01:33:34] "POST /accounts/benjamin/listview HTTP/1.1" 404 7562
```

In Chrome Dev Console, I'm getting this error:

```
jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/benjamin/listview/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)

jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 k.cors.a.crossDomain.send
```

Here is my view method: (note, I just now added @ensure_csrf_cookie after reading other SO posts, but this did not resolve the issue)

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def delete_object(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print "request is ajax"
        object_name = request.POST.get('entryname')
        targetobject = Entry.objects.get(headline=object_name)
        if request.user.username == targetobject.author:
            targetobject.delete()
            print "hello" 
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/storefront/')
```

And AJAX code in the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_app = {
      username: "{{ request.user.username }}"  
    };
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_button").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/accounts/" + my_app.username + "/listview/",
            data: { entryname:id },
            success: function(response){
                alert(response.success);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to pass in the csrf value via JavaScript. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/ for more information.

Comment: I think there is something else going on though because when I use @csrf_exempt, I still get the same 403 forbidden error.

Comment: please list your django urls here

Comment: Give a try:
in settings file
APPEND_SLASH = True

Answer (score 1):

add the csrf token to your ajax request

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I was going to say.

Comment: I added this, but I'm still getting 403 forbidden

Comment: I made a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990202/why-am-i-be-getting-a-403-forbidden-error-when-using-csrf-exempt-in-ajax-reques