# Why am I be getting a 403 Forbidden error when using @csrf_exempt in AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to write a very basic AJAX request in Django, and I keep getting the 403 forbidden error in both the Chrome Dev and Django consoles.  I posted a similar question the other day and have tried all of the proposed solutions including @csrf_exempt (to rule out if this is even a csrf issue), I have tried including csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' in the AJAX POST request (underneath data), this did not resolve the issue either.  Here is my code.

```
def profile_listview(request, username,
    template_name=userena_settings.USERENA_PROFILE_DETAIL_TEMPLATE,
    extra_context=None, **kwargs):
    user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(),
                             username__iexact=username)
    fullsalelist = Entry.objects.filter(author__username__iexact=username)

    @csrf_exempt
    def delete_object(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            print "request is ajax"
            object_name = request.POST.get('entryname')
            targetobject = Entry.objects.get(headline=object_name)
            if request.user.username == targetobject.author:
                targetobject.delete()
                print "hello" 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/storefront/')
```

And AJAX code in the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_app = {
      username: "{{ request.user.username }}"  
    };
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_button").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/accounts/" + my_app.username + "/listview/",
            data: { entryname:id },
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

URLS

```
(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[\@\.\w-]+)/listview/$', profile_listview),
```

Things worth noting:

1. I have csrf middleware turned on in my settings
2. inside the jQuery AJAX code, url and data are both sending the correct information
3. When I click the delete button, I get the 403 forbidden error.
4. The print "request is ajax" does not print in the console (or anywhere).

I am also confused because I am getting conflicting information.  I was told I should add the csrf value via javascript (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/).  This leaves me with 2 questions.  1.  How is this any different than adding csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' in my POST request?  and 2.  More importantly, doesn't the fact that I still get a 403 error when using @csrf_exempt kind of make this a moot point?

Comment: But you are not sending the csrf token in your request.

Comment: Adding the csrf_exempt decorator should remove that restriction, but it's odd that a 403 would be returned.

Comment: On a different note, your JavaScript code will not be able to process the server-side `HttpResponseRedirect`. You would need to pass that back as a string and then do: `top.location = json.redirect_url` for example.

Comment: Are you sure that you call a correct view? Show us  you `urls.py`, please.

Comment: I update the post with my URLS as well as the method 'profile_listview' which contains the method that handles AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, delete_object is a function inside profile_listview, but the profile_listview didn't call it. Therefore, the profile_listview has no http response.
Post the error message

Comment: I ended up moving the AJAX stuff form delete_object to profile_listview.  So I just got rid of delete_object function and put all of it into one function.

Answer (score 2):

The @csrf_exempt needs to be before the function that is called by urls.py. In the OP's example, delete_object was never called because the error happened already when calling profile_listview which didn't have the decorator.

On a side note, one can have a similar situation (using @csrf_exempt but getting 403) if the URL doesn't exist. For some reason (security?), it will return a 403 rather than a 404 so it can be hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

as [catavaran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548165/catavaran) think you called wrong view. You should call delete_object view. For example, add URL

```
(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[\@\.\w-]+)/listview/delete_object$', delete_object)
```

And AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/accounts/" + my_app.username + "/listview/delete_object",
        data: { entryname:id },
    });
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Makes sense, but delete_object is currently INSIDE profile_listview method, so that should work right?  Or no.

Comment: That's should work with some kind of generic views I think. But that's does not look as a proper generic view.  I can not understand how your django handle the delete_object function. If that's should work can you provide article where describe such way of creating views